# UP simple Way to store/retrieve formatted Text

Tags: c#, uwp

currently, I'm using Richeditbox in my to edit and display formatted text in App. there a now a lot of RichEditBoxes. because its the goal of the App, to show a list of formatted text blocks with different Content. The Performance is really slow and the space in DB is great, I'm storing the text in RTF-format in blobs.

What is the easiest way to show simple formatted Text (eg bold, italic)? I never found a quite sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display formatted text you have two options.

`RichTextBlock` is a `TextBlock`-like counterpart of `RichEditBox`. It is however more performant as it just displays the content and does not offer editing.

Alternatively there is a `MarkdownTextBlock` control in the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/markdowntextblock), which can display simple formatted text in the Markdown format.

Comment: thx a milion. this is exact what Im looking for. Fast and simple. well done.